# How to access Parent Variable from Function JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

What's the correct way to access ***x***?

```
let x = 5
const f = (n:number)=> {
  let x = "Welcome";
  return x * n // First x not second x
  }
```

and what's the correct technical name for this operation?

Comment: If you have the same name for both variables, there is no way for the interpreter/(compiler in other languages) to figure out which one to pick. Most languages I know of will either pick the closer one or throw an error

Comment: Give the inner `x` variable a different name (ie: `y`). Currently the inner `x` "shadows" the one from the outer-scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to access a shadowed variable is not to shadow it. Refactor the code by renaming either variable to something else - typically the local one (in the inner scope).

Answer (score -3):

One way is to use block scope and OR operator.

```
{
  let x = 5
  const f = (n) => {
    x = x || "Welcome";
    return x * n // First x not second x
  }
  f(1)
}
```

Another way is to define `x` as a default paramter to `f`

```
let x = 5
const f = (n, z = x)=> {
  let x = "Welcome";
  return z * n // First x not second x
}
```

Comment: The second way actually works and is quite clever. The first way doesn't make sense.

Comment: It makes more than "sense", it works. That block scope can be in the function body as well. Shorter is `x ??= "Welcome"`.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Try x = 0 (after your edit: try x = null) instead of x = 5, and also tell me how to access the "second x"...

Comment: _"No it doesn't work. Try x = 0 instead of x = 5."_ It works. You need to use the correct logic for your application. If you expect 0, adjust accordingly.

Comment: The question how to access a variable in the parent scope with the same name separately from the variable in the current scope is not answered by your first "way", it's the same variable both times. Your second way answers the question with a neat trick that doesn't introduce an extra block and indentation. I'd upvote for the second way, but the first "way" ruins it.

Comment: Vote or don't vote however you want. I don't care about votes. I posted answers to the question I interpreted. It's not clear why `let x = "Welcome";` is in the function at all, if you are in control of the code. We could just put the block scope in the function body if we really need that `const f=()=>{{let x="Welcome";}let x=5}`. However, we don't know why it's there, nor why we are trying to work around it being there. We could just remove that line from the script using `replace()` before running the script, and other things we could do, if we knew why we were doing them.